# Spark Config Files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, high-availability

Can someone share with me the spark-env.sh and spark-default.conf file content which needs to be set to run Spark on YARN as client or cluster ?

Also should i store spark_assembly jar to the HDFS and then create a environment variable in the ~/.bashrc file ?

I am unable to start my spark-shell with --master yarn-client command.
Please help !!

**Update**

```
**Daemon in NN1 :**
2945 JournalNode
3137 DFSZKFailoverController
6385 Jps
3338 NodeManager
22730 QuorumPeerMain
2747 DataNode
3228 ResourceManager
2636 NameNode

**Daemon in NN2** 
19620 Jps
3894 QuorumPeerMain
16966 ResourceManager
16808 NodeManager
16475 DataNode
16572 JournalNode
17101 NameNode
16702 DFSZKFailoverController

**Daemon in DN1**
12228 QuorumPeerMain
29060 NodeManager
28858 DataNode
29644 Jps
28956 JournalNode
```

I am able to invoke spark shell in Stand-alone mode by issuing the following command in terminal

```
$spark-shell
```

But when i try to run the spark-shell in YARN as client then i get the error message

```
$spark-shell --master yarn-client  ---> This command throws out error.
```

My Setup Files for verification :

**Spark-env.sh**

```
#export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"} - I have tried both ways 
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_YARN_QUEUE=default
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=ptfhadoop01v
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=500mb
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

  <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
       <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
       <value>ptfhadoop01v,ntpcam01v</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.ptfhadoop01v</name>
       <value>ptfhadoop01v</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.ntpcam01v</name>
       <value>ntpcam01v</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled</name>
       <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.store.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
       <value>ptfhadoop01v:2181,ntpcam01v:2181,ntpcam03v:2181</value>
       <description>For multiple zk services, separate them with comma</description>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.client.failover-proxy-provider</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider</value>
  </property>

  <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.automatic-failover.zk-base-path</name>
       <value>/yarn-leader-election</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
      <value>yarn-cluster</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I have **NOT** setup any property in my **spark-defaults.conf** file.I am not sure if we need to setup any property in here to make it work.

When trying to launch the spark in yarn-client mode i see the following error ,

```
[hduser@ptfhadoop01v spark-1.6.0]$ spark-shell --master yarn-client --conf   spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://ptfhadoop01v:8020/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar
16/04/08 09:21:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop  library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
  ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_71)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
16/04/08 09:21:37 WARN SparkConf:
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES was detected (set to '2').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --num-executors to specify the number of executors
 - Or set SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES
 - spark.executor.instances to configure the number of instances in the  spark config.

16/04/08 09:21:39 WARN YarnClientSchedulerBackend: NOTE: SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY is deprecated. Use SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY or --executor-memory through spark-submit instead.
16/04/08 09:21:39 WARN YarnClientSchedulerBackend: NOTE: SPARK_WORKER_CORES is deprecated. Use SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES or --executor-cores through spark-submit instead.
16/04/08 09:22:12 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at     org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
    at   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/04/08 09:22:12 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at <init>(<console>:26)
    at .<init>(<console>:30)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$.createListenerAndUI(SQLContext.scala:1367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at <init>(<console>:26)
    at .<init>(<console>:30)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
     import sqlContext.implicits._
            ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
     import sqlContext.sql
            ^

    scala>
```

[image: My ResourceManager Information]

Comment: You need to provide a little more information than this. Why are you unable to start spark-shell? What kind of error messages to you get? I take it that YARN is in fact running on your cluster?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt , I have added more information as per your request. Let me know if you find some issue in my setup files

Comment: No Problem with your SPARK we need fine tune YARN. wats you RAM size because hadoop allocated 8G for the YARN which will be your default values. Configure the Below values in yarn-site according to you RAM in three nodes.
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb.

Problem seems to be executors will collide with Application master since you have allocated MAX container size to 8G(Indefault),By default spark.executor.memory occupies 1 G each while submitting. try to reduce the yarn memory and fine tune the Spark also.

Comment: @karthik , thanks for your inputs , I think this could me the issue, since the memory is much lower than 8GB

ptfhadoop01v - 4GB RAM (Less than 1 GB is free) - Active Namenode
ntpcam01v - 1GB RAM (only 200MB free) - StandBy Namenode
ntpcam03v - 2 GB RAM (600 mb free) - Only act as Datanode.

Each of the machine has only 1 core CPU (This setup is used only to testing purpose on how to install and kickstart Hadoop cluster)

Can you please suggest what should be the appropriate value for those  properties which has to be added into yarn-site.xml

Comment: Have a look at the Cloudera post http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ it's very useful :) Note also that you can specify memory with the `--executor-memory` and `--driver-memory` flags in the `spark-submit` command.

Comment: @AsheshNair well above environment's suits your requirement but doesn't produce much that outcome. lets fine tune your memory. 
 yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 4096
 yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 256
 yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 2250
then tune your spark memory according to the number of container/Application master.

Comment: @karthik, Thanks for those config settings. I tried to alter my yarn-site.xml files with specified settings but still no luck. BTW i read in here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml that the miminum value that can be set for yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb is 1024 and not in increment of 256mb ? I tried to fine tune with below setting

spark-shell --executor-memory 512m --driver-memory 1g --num-executors 2

Comment: @karthik, i have updated all my nodes to have 4GB RAM memory , But still i am facing the same error as before. I was trying to test run  simple SparkPi job in yarn-client mode but it fails as well 



**./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn-client --num-executors 2 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 2 lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar**

Comment: @AsheshNair does spark-submit submitted in YARN ? can you able to locate the Application master logs ? Please update the Application master logs for the SPARK submitt application .!! you visit the Application master logs to get closer .